Time limit exceeded Problem on N variable
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    c=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            if(i+j)%2!=0:
                c+=1
    print(c)

If i give the input to the N is 9999999 the the error occurs How to resolve this Time limit exceeded Problem
To resolve my problem.

This is a math problem pretending to be a coding problem print(n * n//2)

The two for loops do not seem the best approach to your problem. Given the expected result, you could compute the result values directly.
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    print((n // 2) * (n + (n % 2)))


Note that despite the downvote, I believe this produces the correct answer and is many orders of magnitude faster.
